# Hightlight numbers in phone number

Tags: javascript, phone-number

This function hightlight numbers.

```
var hightlightPhoneNumbers = function(phoneNumber, hNumbers) {
  var splitPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.split(hNumbers);
  var result = '';

  if (splitPhoneNumber.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < splitPhoneNumber.length - 1; i++) {
      result += splitPhoneNumber[i] + '<b>' + hNumbers + '</b>';
    }
    return result + splitPhoneNumber[splitPhoneNumber.length - 1];
  }
  return phoneNumber;
};
```

And we can usage it as `hightlightPhoneNumbers('+123456789','123')`.

But we have a little problem. What if phone number looks like +1 234-567-89?
Ofcourse function doesnt work correct. How we can to fix it?

Hightlight means wrap numbers in tags   or something. see http://jsfiddle.net/QhJWt/3/

Comment: Abstract this. How can you highlight a substring? The fact it's a phone number doesn't matter. A more general solution exists.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? What does "highlighting numbers" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function hightlightPhoneNumbers(phoneNumber, clip) {
    var re = new RegExp(clip.split('').join('[\\s-]*'), 'gi');
    return phoneNumber.replace(re, '<b>$&</b>');
}
```

By the way, there is this funny non-standard method of [`String.prototype.bold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#HTML_wrapper_methods) that wraps a string into a `<b></b>` tag.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oxiqot).